# Validity of: ◻◇◻p → ◇p in transitive frames

Tags: logic, proof-theory, modal-logic, relations

How can I show the (in)validity of: ◻◇◻p → ◇p in a transitive frame?

Proof method: I want to do this by showing in a transitive frame that ◻◇◻p holds and that ◇p doesn't hold.

(I think that ◻◇◻p would never hold in a transitive frame and that the implication is then automatically right, is this correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: any sentence of the form "$\Diamond \varphi$" is *not true* in any world (in any frame) with no arrows coming out of it. Does transitivity imply that the accessibility relation is nontrivial?

You should think about the simplest frame possible, here; this frame $F_0$ will be transitive, and will have the property that

- $\neg\Diamond p$ is valid in $F_0$

but

- $\Box\Diamond\Box p$ is *also* valid in $F_0$,

so it is a counterexample to the claim that $\Box\Diamond\Box p\implies\Diamond p$ in transitive frames.

---

What happens if we add *reflexivity* - which does imply that the accessibility relation is nontrivial - to the mix?

Comment: ◻p→ ◇p for example by seriality of F we know that x
has at least one R-successor. Meaning access atleast one is true and in an serial frame,◻◇◻◇p → ◻◇p would be valid in a reflexivity and transitive frame. But I dont understand how it is possible that this one is valid in just a transitive frame.

Comment: @TanjaMeeren It's **not** valid in a merely transitive frame. The point of my hint was to show you how to come up with a *counterexample*. What's the simplest frame you can think of?

Comment: Then arbitrary model with arbitrary point: M=(a,b,c,x) c⊨◻x by cRx, next b⊨◇◻x , a⊨◻◇◻x, the problem is that i can not think of frame  where this would hold.

But transitivity frame would correspond with ◇◇p ->◇p or ◻p ->◻◻p meaning iff a R b and b R c(x/p) together imply a R c. for all points

To make ◻◇◻p true I would need a extra element in the transitivity  to make the formula true in an transitive frame (I think that is what you meant right?)
Is the solution more simpeler then I think? That a have to be in two steps at x and that this does not hold: Because a⊨◇c, but c⊭x

Comment: @TanjaMeeren You're trying *way* too hard. Like I said above, what's the simplest frame you can think of?  Forget this particular problem for a second, just think frames - what's an example of a really simple one?

Comment: Meanwhile, I can't understand your claim "I think that ◻◇◻p would never hold in a transitive frame" - why would that be true? For any frame $F$ and any modal sentence $\sigma$ without negation, there is a truth assignment to $F$ such that $\sigma$ is true at every world in $F$. Maybe you mean that that expression is never *valid* in a transitive frame? Well, that's false too . . .

Comment: The most simple one, just showing that ◻◇◻p holds which actually can hold, but then ◇p does not hold.

Comment: @TanjaMeeren I think you're misunderstanding my question. I'm asking: **what is the simplest frame you can think of**? I'm really thinking about *a specific frame*: some set of worlds, together with some accessibility relation. So, for the third time: what's the simplest frame you can think of?

Comment: You mean a frame that hold in transitivity, wRv ⋂ vRu -> wRu
Or do you mean for before the implication? aRb ⋂ bRc ⋂ cRd
Where then a does not have R(successor)d?

Comment: @TanjaMeeren You're trying to go too fast; start simpler. **Forget the question at hand, just describe the simplest frame you can**. An actual frame - some collection of worlds, and some accessibility relation. What's the *absolute simplest* frame you can think of?

Comment: A frame with just one point and that has no successor. 
Described in model: M,w |= T <-> w∈ [T] M

Comment: @TanjaMeeren Bingo! Call that frame $F_0$. Now, note the following: (i) $F_0$ is transitive (why?). (ii) Any expression of the form "$\Box\varphi$" is valid in $F_0$ (why?). (iii) Any expression of the form "$\Diamond\varphi$" is invalid in $F_0$ (why?). Can you prove these three facts? If so, do you see how they imply that "$\Box\Diamond\Box p\implies \Diamond p$" is *not* necessarily valid in a transitive frame?

Comment: (i)This holds inside the transitive frame (ii)◻φ⊨⊤it is blind, no matter definition this holds)  (iii)◊φ has some successor if this would be true ◊φ⊨⊤
Last part is not true because  ◊φ⊭⊤ meaning ◊φ⊨⊥
Is this correct?

Comment: @TanjaMeeren I don't understand any of your explanations. What do you mean by "$p\models q$" for $p, q$ modal sentences? Your explanations need to reference something about *this specific frame*, which as far as I can tell they don't.